# Atmospheric conductance equation

Tags: rstudio

I am starting to learn about rstudio and I need to make a function of the atmospheric conductance equation,

```
Cat = Vm / 6.25*[ln ((Zm - Zd) / Z0)]^2
where:
Zv - vegetation height
Zd - zero plane displacement ( 0.7 x Zveg )
Z0 - roughness height ( 0.1x Zveg )
Vm - wind speed

the Cat function is in cm/s and I need to return it in mm/s
```

How I should write this function??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a basic question such as this, it may be easier (and faster) to do a quick Google search, such as "How to write a function in R", which yields many results such as [How to Write and Debug an R Function](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-write-and-debug-an-r-function/)

Comment: Once you have researched and begun solving your problem, Stack Overflow is a great resource to turn to if you are stuck and need help progressing, *once you have already tried solving the problem yourself* :)

Answer (score 0):

Roughly,

```
atmospheric_conductance <- function(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...){
    cat = (arg1 / 6.25 * [ln ((arg2 - arg3) / arg4)]^2)
    return(cat)
}
```

Refer to [R Operations](https://www.statmethods.net/management/operators.html) for how to write numerical computation in R.

Comment: `cat` is a build in function name. Dont use `cat` as variable name, Why `...` ? How can you set `arg4` in this setup.

Comment: I got it! Thanks!